# How to read external properties based on value of local variable in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

let say I have the following properties in my application.properties

```
url.2019=http://example.com/2019
url.2020=http://example.com/2020
```

And I have this method,

```
public String getUrl(String year) {

    String url;

    // here I want to read the property value based on the value of year
    // if year is "2019", I want to get the value of ${url.2019}
    // if year is "2020", I want to get the value of ${url.2020}
    // something like #{url.#{year}} ??

    return url;
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be multiple ways to achieve this

**If your properties are not managed by spring**

https://www.baeldung.com/inject-properties-value-non-spring-class

**If it is managed by spring**

1.) you can define a map in application.properies, can inject the map in your code read whichever property you want

2) you can inject environment variable and read property on demand

```
@Autowired 
private Environment environment;

public String getUrl(String year) {

    String url = "url." + year ;

    String value =environment.getProperty(url);

    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

application.properties:

```
url.2019=https://
url.2020=https://
```

Code, just use `@ConfigurationProperties` is mandatory for the Map field, otherwise, you don't get values.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("put here property file path")
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class ConfigProperties {

    @Value($("url"))
    Map<String,String> urlMap;


    public String getUrl(String year) {
      String url = urlMap.get(year);
      System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```