# How to fetch file from azure blob using spring boot

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I want to fetch files from Azure blob storage. Following code does it fine-

```
package com.<your-resource-group>.<your-artifact-name>;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("blob")
public class BlobController {

    @Value("azure-blob://<your-container-name>/<your-blob-name>")
    private Resource blobFile;

    @GetMapping("/readBlobFile")
    public String readBlobFile() throws IOException {
        return StreamUtils.copyToString(
                this.blobFile.getInputStream(),
                Charset.defaultCharset());
    }

    @PostMapping("/writeBlobFile")
    public String writeBlobFile(@RequestBody String data) throws IOException {
        try (OutputStream os = ((WritableResource) this.blobFile).getOutputStream()) {
            os.write(data.getBytes());
        }
        return "file was updated";
    }
}
```

My Question -

The @Value annotation provides value to the Resource that is static (i.e I cannot put any variable containing my path as a string inside @Value).

How can I implement the this

Answer (score 0):

In application properties try storing the path

```
#application.properties
blob.path=
```

We can use `@Value("${...property's name}")` annotation to access the above property in the Java class as follows:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ValueController {

    @Value("${blob.path}") 
    private String path;

    @GetMapping("")
    ..
    }
}
```

Here try to use *blob uri  complete path* in application properties and use the same in @value annotation as variable by map datatype

```
//
    @Value("${blob.path}") 
private Map<String, String>  blobPath;
```

See this > [java - How to read external properties based on value of local variable in Spring Boot? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58637191/how-to-read-external-properties-based-on-value-of-local-variable-in-spring-boot/58637294#58637294)
**&**   [Value Spring: Spring @Value annotation tricks - DEV Community](https://dev.to/habeebcycle/spring-value-annotation-tricks-1a80?msclkid=6025fa15cf5e11ecb051e520da5876ef)

Also see [Requestmapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)

**Other references :**

1. [Spring Azure Blob Storage | DevGlan](https://www.devglan.com/spring-mvc/spring-azure-blob-storage?msclkid=fd6de6dbcf6211ecae5ef58514066979)
2. [**spring batch - How to read the csv files from Azure Blob Storage in
   Java with folder structure as 'dir1 / dir2 / dir3 /..'? - Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67080921/how-to-read-the-csv-files-from-azure-blob-storage-in-java-with-folder-structure?msclkid=fd6f6aa8cf6211ec81c25c6d47543465)